# Django get values from field after order_by

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to get the shared values from a field after ordering my model based on one of its fields. So for example I have a model named `Course`:

```
class Course(models.Model):

    code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    instructor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and then for ordering based on instructor I do:

`Course.objects.all().order_by('instructor').distinct('instructor')`

Which will then give me for example

1. ABC123, Uni1, Adamson
2. EFG456, Uni1, Adamson
3. HIJ789, Uni1, James
4. KLM321, Uni1, James

How can I retrieve the results as a dictionary with the keys being the instructor and the value being a query set of model object? So I will get something such as:

```
result = {
"Adamson":<QuerySet[]>,
"James":<QuerySet[]>
}
```

I cannot find an aggregate function that does this is there any way to do this using a single method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can post-process the data with the [**`groupby(…)`** function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of the [**`itertools`** module [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Course.objects.all().order_by('instructor')

result = {
    k: list(vs)
    for k, vs in groupby(qs, attrgetter('instructor'))
}
```

Comment: @ashes999: it will work with `ForeignKey`s, since Django models are hashable. The only thing that you should do is then use `.select_related('name_of_foreignkey')`, to prevent making an extra query per `Course` item.

Comment: Thanks, however, this will not allow any pagination am I correct?

Comment: @ashes999: you can paginate the queryset *before* post-processing it. But the problem with pagination here is that it is not entirely clear how that should look like: you here have a dictionary with *multiple* lists as values. So how would you paginate it? This is thus more a matter of *specification* than *implementation*.

Comment: So there is no optimal way to achieve pagination with the current specifications since, the query set will return all the Courses grouped by the instructor so it is not possible to paginate based on each instructor unless writing a different method? (Filtering based on instructor)

Comment: @ashes999: the problem is: what would *pagination* be here? How would page 1 look like? and page 2?